# How to get a list of days from July 4th to Oct 4th over a range of years

Tags: date-and-time

I'd like to create a list with days from the 4th of July to the 4th of October starting in July 1970 to the current date. I tried to use `DateRange`, but I'm a bit confused cause the documentation is't very clear on this point.

What should I do? Have you ever tried to do such a thing?

Comment: You mean from the 4th of July to the 4th of October of every year?

Comment: Some important things that you left out from your question: how do you want to results to be formatted and how do you plan to use them later?

Comment: @Öskå yes, exactly, but the current year I need to stop to the present date (if we're still on summer, otherwise I take the nearest past summer) :D

Comment: @m_goldberg i need them in list format, or list of DateObject... like this {{1970, 07, 04},{1970, 07, 05} ...}

Comment: Does my most recent edit of the title characterize your question correctly?

Comment: Does this produce your desired result: `Flatten[DateRange[{#, 7, 4}, {#, 10, 4}, "Day"] & /@ 
  Range[1974, 2013], 1]`?

Comment: @ubpdqn. I'm reading this as the entire summer after the 7/4 up to the current year.  if current date of current year is after 4th but before the end of summer, it ends there, otherwise, to end of most recent summer.

Comment: @m_goldberg I am still somewhat uncertain..."summer" is somewhat problematic...perhaps its just my antipodean perspective...as these dates are "winter" for me...I posed my comment as a question for clarification of my confusion.

Comment: @ubpdqn, thanks, that's what I meant

Comment: OK, I misinterpreted the question. I'll fix the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from @ubpdqn, my interpretation of the question (which, hopefully, should also be valid in 2015):

```
td = Today // Normal;
{cy, cm, cd} = Take[td, 3];
days = Flatten[DateRange[{#, 7, 4}, {#, 10, 4}, "Day"] & /@ Range[1970, cy], 1];

Which[
 Today > Interpreter["Date"]["04/October/" <> ToString@cy], days,
 Today < Interpreter["Date"]["04/July/" <> ToString@cy], DeleteCases[days, {cy, __}], True,
 DeleteCases[days, {y_, m_, d_} /; y == cy && m > cm || y == cy && m == cm && d > cd]]
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer is based on @eldo's and @ubpdqn's answer (thanks guys!). Remove `// Flatten[#, 1] &` to get the dates grouped into years.

```
Clear[seismaticaDates]
seismaticaDates[year_,{mfrom_,dfrom_},{mto_,dto_},{cy_,cm_,cd_}]:=
Module[{dateRangeFunc,allDates},
dateRangeFunc=DateRange[{#,mfrom,dfrom},{#,mto,dto}]&;
(* Defining 2 allDates functions to prevent counting days
when the date of the current year hasn't reached the starting date of the interval 
i.e. take the "nearest past summer" *)
allDates[{y_,m_,d_}/;m<mfrom||m==mfrom&&d<dfrom]:=dateRangeFunc/@Range[year,y-1];
allDates[{y_,m_,d_}]:=dateRangeFunc/@Range[year,y];
DeleteCases[allDates[{cy,cm,cd}],{cy,m_,d_}/;m>cm||(m==cm&&d>cd),{2}]//Flatten[#,1]&]

seismaticaDates[1970,{7,4},{10,4},Take[Normal@Today,3]]
{{1970,7,4},{1970,7,5},{1970,7,6},{1970,7,7},{1970,7,8},{1970,7,9},{1970,7,10},{1970,7,11},{1970,7,12},{1970,7,13},{1970,7,14},{1970,7,15},{1970,7,16},{1970,7,17}, ...4096... ,{2014,7,22},{2014,7,23},{2014,7,24},{2014,7,25},{2014,7,26},{2014,7,27},{2014,7,28},{2014,7,29},{2014,7,30},{2014,7,31},{2014,8,1},{2014,8,2},{2014,8,3},{2014,8,4}}

seismaticaDates[1970,{7,4},{10,4},{2015,1,3}]
{{1970,7,4},{1970,7,5},{1970,7,6},{1970,7,7},{1970,7,8},{1970,7,9},{1970,7,10},{1970,7,11},{1970,7,12},{1970,7,13},{1970,7,14},{1970,7,15},{1970,7,16},{1970,7,17}, ...4157... ,{2014,9,21},{2014,9,22},{2014,9,23},{2014,9,24},{2014,9,25},{2014,9,26},{2014,9,27},{2014,9,28},{2014,9,29},{2014,9,30},{2014,10,1},{2014,10,2},{2014,10,3},{2014,10,4}}
```

---

**Comparison with @eldo's method**

My method seems to not require any Internet connection (as compared to @eldo's method), and it seems to run faster as well.

```
eldoDates=Module[{td,cy,cm,cd,days},
td=Today//Normal;
{cy,cm,cd}=Take[td,3];
days=Flatten[DateRange[{#,7,4},{#,10,4},"Day"]&/@Range[1970,cy],1];
Which[Today>Interpreter["Date"]["04/October/"<>ToString@cy],days,Today<Interpreter["Date"]["04/July/"<>ToString@cy],DeleteCases[days,{cy,__}],True,DeleteCases[days,{y_,m_,d_}/;y==cy&&m>cm||y==cy&&m==cm&&d>cd]]]//AbsoluteTiming;

s1=seismaticaDates[1970,{7,4},{10,4},Take[Normal@Today,3]]//AbsoluteTiming;
First/@{s1,eldoDates}
(* {0.069004,0.776044} *)

Equal[Rest@s1, Rest@eldoDates]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Again with the understanding that an answer has already been accepted. I submit the following only as an exercise:

```
    Clear[repeatdaterange];
repeatdaterange[startdate_, enddate_] := Module[{startyear, startmonth, startday, endyear, endmonth,endday, curyear, curmonth, curday, stopyear, stepping, lastmonth, listofdates, rangeofdates},
{startyear, startmonth, startday} = startdate;
{ endyear, endmonth,endday} = enddate;
 {curyear, curmonth, curday} = Take[DateList[],3];
stopyear = If[curmonth >=startmonth, curyear, Subtract[curyear,1] ];
stepping = Subtract[endmonth ,startmonth];
lastmonth = If[curmonth>=endmonth &&  curday >= endday,endmonth,curmonth];
listofdates =Table[{i,j,startday}, {i,startyear,stopyear}, {j,startmonth,If[i == stopyear,lastmonth,endmonth],stepping} ];
listofdates = If[First[Dimensions[Last[listofdates] ]] ==  1, ReplacePart[ listofdates, Length[listofdates] -> {Last[listofdates][[1]],{stopyear,lastmonth,curday } }],listofdates ];
rangeofdates = Apply[DateRange, listofdates,1]
]
```

One can add another parameter to the function for final date instead of current runtime in the DateList[{insert final date here}]. There may be small boundary issues but this runs fairly fast.